# firefox gmap api V3 infowindow scroll different with chrome & safari

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am a little nervous as this is my first post in this beautiful admirable community...

Here is my problem : I have a set of markers with infowindow on a map, using google maps API V3.19.

Some of the infowindow contents are bigger than size, so I *want* a scrollbar in the infowindow (not like many post who want to make the scrollbar disappear)

All my infowindow contents are inside a div, and I manage to put z-index on top everytime I open a new infowindow.

Safari and chrome : works perfectly;the scrollbar is on, and when I scroll with mouse inside the infowindow, the content of the infowindow scrolls down.

Firefox : if I scroll with cursor inside the infowindow, it is the map which zooms in or out, not the content which scrolls down. And it is hard to get the scroll bar, which is the only way to scroll the content.

All this on Mac OSx

Extract from my css : markerInfoWin is the class of the div wrapping the content

```
#map-canvas div{
   overflow:scroll !important;
}

.markerInfoWin {
    border-top: 12px solid;
    width: 290px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

and javascript when I open an infowindow named infoWin:

```
var zindex = globalZindex + 1;
this.infoWin.setContent(this.contentInfoWin_);
this.infoWin.setZIndex(zindex);
$("#" + this.infoWin.divname).css('z-index', zindex);
globalZindex = zindex;
this.infoWin.open(kflowMap, this.markerCont);
```

Thank you if one has any hint, or if it is a firefox bug !

Best regards

Comment: Any live URL where this can be tested? Or can you create a fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have an answer.

It is a unfortunatly a "bug" in Firefox

https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/issues/detail?id=328

Very annoying...

Thanks everyone